# Is Swift's native Array type memory inefficient?

Tags: arrays, swift, dynamic, capacity

I'm currently building my own dynamic array type, which also implements the `reserveCapacity` method. Since my array type dynamically resizes it's capacity I was wondering how the behaviour would be in Swift's `Array` type.
Was it just going to keep the capacity until the size of the array is changed the next time? - no.
When calling the `reserveCapacity` function it keeps the capacity (or more) of the array that way **forever** (unless you call `removeAll`).
I found this to be very weird, since it seems very space inefficient to have alot of allocated space with nothing occupying it.
But then I thought, that this might just be the way `reserveCapacity` is supposed to work.
But then I wanted to know if Swift's `Array`s ever reduce their size - they don't.

How does [this](http://swiftstub.com/363094414/) make sense?

Also I noticed, that the capacity grows exponentially at the beginning (`2 -> 4 -> 8 -> ...`), but when it reaches `64` it goes weird (`64 -> 188 -> 388 -> ...`), as seen [here](http://swiftstub.com/563855460/). Why would they do this?

Comment: To have a mutable array constantly resize itself every time you add an item can lead to unnecessary memory fragmentation. I'm a little surprised that there isn't a reduce capacity method (other than removing all or re-instantiating) which we might call upon memory pressure. Regarding the jumps in the capacity, I assume it's a mixture of (a) optimizing memory boundaries; and (b) some probabilistic model (e.g. based upon the current capacity size, how likely you are to add a certain number of items, and the cost of expanding the capacity).